# WPF Designer and Entity Framework

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

I develop my first application using *WPF/MVVM* and *Entity Framework 6*. Currently I am having a hard time to show my *XAML* in designer correctly if it is bound to data coming from *Entity Framework*.

I am aware of the different possibilities to supply design time data but i prefer to use an instance of my ViewModel during design time to have real data. But it seems to be impossible to get *EF* working during design time because of the missing app.conf which is not used in design time.

So I thought maybe I can mock *EF* - not for testing - but for providing data at design time. I've read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx) article but with this method I do not fake the complete *EF*, for example my `DbSet.Load()` or `DbSet.Locale` will fail.

So what is the the best way to provide design time data in my situation?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no data is loaded in Design mode. Are you really sure that the delay associated with loading the data?

Edit: Do you meant with design-time, development-time, thus testing the application at runtime? In this case, you can limit the number of records with "Take". For example

```
yourRepository.GetAll().Take(10); // you can get a list: .Take(10).ToList();
```

Comment: I am not sure if you understood my question correctly. Nowhere I speak of a delay and with "design time" i mean that time when the application is not running but displayed in visual studio or blend.

Comment: Ok, I do not think it is possible to read data in design mode from a database and display. If you can still find a way, please let us know;-)

Comment: A litle overview about designtime you can get here: http://wpftutorial.net/DesigntimeVsRuntime.html